# How do you create a new order in paypal here from an iOS homescreen webapp?

Tags: ios, web-applications, paypal

I am aware that PayPal Here can be accessed via an iOS URL scheme similar to: "paypalhere://takePayment?arguments".

I don't know what this URL scheme is but people have already been able to do what I am trying to do, a sample can be read here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPalHere-Sample/blob/master/PPHSample/PPHSample/PPHSampleViewController.m at line 171.

I just want to open paypal here and at the very least pass the total and receive a pass/fail callback. Now if you know how to create an entire order (product name,price,quantity), that would be even better!

Please help me out! I haven't been able to figure it out from reading this ViewController and it looks like it's the only thing that hints at how to get it done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this comment:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/1#issuecomment-14680084

It has 2 documents that may be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you! I had already received this link like 2 hours before you answered! But still, much appreciated.